# Debug the instance/class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

I'm trying to get the following code to work as intended in the comments below. For instance, I will create three Dog instances using the commands below (dogs: buddy, pascal, and kimber). However, when running `buddy.teach('sit')`, it adds the 'sit' trick to both buddy and pascal instances. Can you please manipulate the code so that the attribute is defined for the instance objects rather than the class object?

Please only edit the code (do not change the commands in the comments below).

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, tricks=set()):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = tricks
    def teach(self, trick):
        self.tricks.add(trick)
```

```
# Change the broken code above so that the following lines work:
# 
# buddy = Dog('Buddy')
# pascal = Dog('Pascal')
# kimber = Dog('Kimber', tricks={'lie down', 'shake'})
# buddy.teach('sit')
# pascal.teach('fetch')
# buddy.teach('roll over')
# kimber.teach('fetch')
# print(buddy.tricks)  # {'sit', 'roll over'}
# print(pascal.tricks)  # {'fetch'}
# print(kimber.tricks)  # {'lie down', 'shake', 'fetch'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your default argument `tricks=set()` in `__init__`.

Default arguments are only evaluated once, when the function/method gets defined. So, a empty `set` gets created, which will be used as the default argument whenever `__init__` gets called without specifying `tricks`.

When you execute `buddy = Dog('Buddy')`, this empty set gets used as `tricks`, and in `self.tricks = tricks`, you make the `tricks` attribute of `buddy` refer to it.

Later, you execute `pascal = Dog('Pascal')`, again without specifying `trick`, so the same set created as the default argument gets used, and the `trick` attribute of `pascal` will also refer to it.

So, both instances share the same set for tricks.

There would be no problem if you passed a value for `tricks` when creating an instance: it would be an independant set.
There wouldn't be any problem either if this default weren't mutable (see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

In order to avoid using a mutable default argument, the classic solution is as follows:

```
 class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, tricks=None):
        if tricks is None:
            tricks = set()
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = tricks
        
    def teach(self, trick):
        self.tricks.add(trick)
        
buddy = Dog('Buddy')
pascal = Dog('Pascal')
kimber = Dog('Kimber', tricks={'lie down', 'shake'})
buddy.teach('sit')
pascal.teach('fetch')
buddy.teach('roll over')
kimber.teach('fetch')
print(buddy.tricks)  # {'sit', 'roll over'}
print(pascal.tricks)  # {'fetch'}
print(kimber.tricks)  # {'lie down', 'shake', 'fetch'}
```

Output:

```
{'roll over', 'sit'}
{'fetch'}
{'lie down', 'fetch', 'shake'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth break down!

Answer (score 1):

### Here you go:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, tricks=set()):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = set(tricks)
    def teach(self, trick):
        self.tricks.add(trick)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init()__` has the following definition:

```
def __init__(self, name, tricks=set()):
```

That `set()` is and object, which is instantiated once for the class *definition* and shared in each instance. So every instance that uses the default `tricks` share the same set of tricks(!).

To prevent this, a common pattern is:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, tricks=None):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = set()
        if tricks:
            self.tricks = tricks
    def teach(self, trick):
        self.tricks.add(trick)
```